# Crossfade images with AngularJS and jade

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug, image-gallery, ng-animate

I'm a newbie to AngularJS and want to create a timer for a crossfade image gallery what changes images every few seconds.

Here is what I have already:

Angular Controller:

```
app.controller('aboutController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-about';

    $http.get('./assets/json/gallery.json').then(function (response) {
        //Parse and save json to array/object
        $scope.gallery_items = response.data;
    });

    $scope.selectedImage = 0;
    $scope.setSelected = function(selected){
    $scope.selectedImage = selected;
    }
}]);
```

Jade Template:

```
     div
        a(data-ng-click="setSelected(0)")
            p Select 1
        a(data-ng-click="setSelected(1)")
            p Select 2
        a(data-ng-click="setSelected(2)")
            p Select 3
        div(data-ng-repeat="item in gallery_items" class="image-repeat")
            img(data-ng-src='{{item.img}}' alt="{{item.alt}}" title="{{item.title}}" data-ng-show="selectedImage==$index" data-ng-animate="{show: 'animate-show', hide: 'animate-hide'}").img-responsive
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: ...how can I create a timer for a crossfade image gallery what changes images every few seconds in angularJS and jade...

Comment: there are lots of available scripts already for this. Find one with features you want and start there.

Comment: I already have the features I want and a working gallery.. I only need the timer that changes the src-attribute every few seconds..